# Error: undefined reference to `censorship()'

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have `main.cpp`:

```
#include "censorship_dec.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    censorship();
    return 0;
}
```

this is my `censorship_dec.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void censorship();
```

this is my `censorship_mng.cpp`:

```
#include "censorship_dec.h"
using namespace std;

void censorship()
{
   cout << "bla bla bla" << endl;
}
```

I tried to run these files in SSH (Linux), so I wrote: `make main`, but I got:

```
g++     main.cpp   -o main
/tmp/ccULJJMO.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `censorship()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

please help!

Comment: try change censorship_mng.cpp to censorship_dec.cpp

Comment: or use something like `g++ main.cpp censorship_mng.cpp -o main`

Comment: try linking in *all* your compiled source files. Your compilation line only lists one: main.cpp

Comment: @someone_smiley, is there an option how to fix it without changing the name of the file? the lecturer wants us to send the exercise with these names. thank you!

Comment: @WhozCraig, I'm sorry but I didn't understand you

Comment: not sure if u can compromise on having definition of censorship() move to .h instead?

Comment: try [censored] and you'll be fine.

Comment: why the f*** do you have `using namespace std;` in every single file? It's only needed where you use `cout` and `endl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the file where `censorship` is defined.

```
g++ main.cpp censorship_mng.cpp -o main
```

Comment: in my function of censorship, I have another callings to another functions. so I got: /tmp/ccBpBk4A.o: In function `censorship()':
censorship_mng.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `read_files(char*, char*)'
censorship_mng.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `make_string(int&, char*, char (*) [21])'
censorship_mng.cpp:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `read_files(char*, char*)'
censorship_mng.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `make_string(int&, char*, char (*) [21])'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to add the files those symbols are defined in too.

Answer (score 3):

You must add `censorship_mng.cpp` in your compilation command:

> g++ main.cpp censorship_mng.cpp -o main

---

Another solution (if you really don't want change your compile command) is making `void censorship();` to a `inline` function and move it from `.cpp` to `.h`.

`censorship_dec.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

inline void censorship()
{
  // your code
}
```

And remove `void censorship()` from `censorship_mng.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

once your project starts using several source-files to be compiled into a single binary, manual compilations become tedious.

this is usually the time when you start using a build-system, such as a [Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

a very simple Makefile that uses default build-rules could look like

```
default: main

# these flags are here only for illustration purposes
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include
CFLAGS=-g -O3
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3
LDFLAGS=-lm

# objects (.o files) will be compiled automatically from matching .c and .cpp files
OBJECTS=bar.o bla.o foo.o main.o

# application "main" build-depends on all the objects (and linksthem together)
main: $(OBJECTS)
```